# Different route key name for a single route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I know I can change the route key name for whole model using `getRouteKeyName` method, but how can I change the route key name for a single route? Let's say I have a Post model and the route key name obviously is `id`, I want to have `slug` key name for the `show` route. Is it possible to manage `getRouteKeyName` method somehow to achieve that?

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Comment: Just use slug in your function `public function show($slug){ model::where('slug', $slug)->first();` you get your model show by slug or any other field as you wish. `ps` post model by default is `id` you can change that accordingly as well.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, But the problem is I'm using post show route everywhere and I don't want to pass the slug parameter to the route method everytime like `route( 'posts.show', [ 'post' => $post->slug ] )`

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution :)

In `AppServiceProvider` class I added the following code to the `boot` method.

```
Route::bind('posts.show', function ($value) {
    return App\Post::where('slug', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```

Comment: In stead of `AppServiceProvider`, you should use `RouteServiceProvider`.